# How to Count or Sum the String columns values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have employees attendance table from date 1 to 31 with column names like 1, 2, 3, 4 5.....31
and datatype is nVarchar(5)

I am adding values in those columns (P, H, A) for example:

P = Present
A = Absence
H = Holiday

Now i want to calculate Total (P=Present) in last column that is [TotalPresnets] of Employee.
How to calculate (Count) the string values.

Comment: You have 31 columns called 1, 2, ..., 31? I don't think it's a good design.

Comment: it don't matter but i want to know if there is a way to solve this one!!!

Like to make a loop or make a stored procedure or function any solution ??????????????????

Comment: How do you handle 28 or 30 day months?

Comment: another option would be to create a normalized view of the query and use that as your source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you made 31 columns, every type of manipulation will involve fetching all 31 of those columns. This is one of a million reasons why this design is going to cause you a lot of pain. So, I have to say you need to consider changing this design!

If you must stick with this, you will end up with code something like this:

```
select
    EmployeeID,
    (
        case when Day0 = 'P' then 1 else 0 end
        + case when Day1 = 'P' then 1 else 0 end
        + case when Day2 = 'P' then 1 else 0 end
        ...
        + case when Day31 = 'P' then 1 else 0 end
    ) as TotalPresent
from
    Attendance
```

Another ugly solution would be to use dynamic SQL to generate the query above.

In general, when you are forced into such ugly solutions, it's a good indication that you are approaching the problem wrong.

Note also that this is some 40 lines of code for a very basic operation on a single row. Carrying this technique into the rest of your application is going to cause far more headaches. Imagine if you had to change any logic in here; what should be one line is now 31.

A better design would yield more intuitive / maintainable / readable code:

```
select
    EmployeeID,
    count(*) TotalPresent
from
    EmployeeDailyAttendance eda
    inner join Days d on d.ID = eda.DayID
where
    eda.Code = 'p'
group by
    EmployeeID
```

Comment: `you will end up with code something like this` I give you two elegant alternatives in my answer

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2008 is wonderful. Have a look at this examples:

Table for discussion

```
create table attendance(
empid int,
[1] char(1), [2] char(1), [3] char(1), [4] char(1),
[5] char(1), [6] char(1), [7] char(1), [8] char(1));

insert attendance values
(1,'P','P','H','A','A','P','P','P'),
(2,'P','P','P','P','P','P','P',null),
(3,'P','P','H','P','P','P',null,null);
```

Your select statement options (expand as required to 31 days)

#### Nested select

```
select empid,
 (select COUNT(*)
  from (values([1]),([2]),([3]),([4]),([5]),([6]),([7]),([8])) t(Day)
  where Day='P')
from attendance
```

#### Unpivot

```
select empid, count(day)
from attendance
unpivot (type for day in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8])) unp
where type='P'
group by empid
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with Mark here.  Your current design makes it very difficult to query by date.  I recommend using a date field and a status field.  You'll have one row per employee, per day, but it will much easier to get the results you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I know that what folks have said is true. Still, you have to most likely deliver the project rather soon, so i thought i'd give you a hand

```
<?php
$month = escape_month_securely();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE month = '$month'");

// loop through rows. 
while(false !== ($row = mysql_fetch_object())) {
    // loop through cols
    foreach($row as $key => $col) {
        if($key != $userID)
        $split = str_split($col);
        // loop through letters
        foreach($split as $letter) {
            $final_results[$row->userID][$letter]++;
        }
    }
}

print_r($final_results);

/*
 * outputs something like
 * array(
 *  '15' => array(
 *      'P' => 19,
 *      'A' => 4,
 *      'H' => 1
 * )
 *  '13' => array(
 *      'P' => 19,
 *      'A' => 4,
 *      'H' => 1
 * )
 * );
*/
```

Most likely you are not using PHP but some other language, but the idea is simple. Loop through all columns, skipping only columns that are not days, summing every individual letter and storing it into an array.

Hope this is of use to you.

Regards,
Pedro

Answer (score 0):

I posted as a comment, but think it may be better as an answer.

Create a view of your table:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, '1' As DayOfMonth, Day1 As AttendanceValue FROM TableName
UNION
SELECT EmployeeID, '2', Day2 FROM TableName
....
SELECT EmployeeID, '31', Day31 FromTableName
```

now you can use a query similar to tenfour's:

```
SELECT AttendanceValue, COUNT(AttendanceValue) FROM ViewName GORUP BY AttendanceValue
```